# Having issue with font not being vertically aligned in websites

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am having an issue with building websites where various different fonts (we use fonts from Adobe Fonts) will not be vertically aligned within their content space, making it difficult to create symmetrical buttons. The gapping is different from font to font, which just increases the issue.

For this particular font (quasimoda), the image below shows the issue I'm having. For those unfamiliar, the orange color is margin, the green color is padding, and the blue color (where the text lies) is the content area of the box model. The text itself sticks to the top of the blue content section, giving the appearance of an off vertically centered button (shown below the box model), even though the padding is identical on top and bottom (left and right padding are intentionally different).

Is there some way (assuming a CSS rule) to make the text lie in the center of the blue content section of the box model?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are using all caps. If you put a character with a descender in there you will see that the system is reserving space for it. Different typefaces have different amounts of space for ascenders/descenders. I've not found a satisfactory way of dealing with this in a generalisable way with just CSS. Sometimes have drawn the characters on a canvas and checked with JS where the (visible) tops and bottoms of various characters are! Hope someone can suggest something better.

Answer (score 0):

in the div where your text is you need to put:

```
dipslay:flex;
align-items:center;
text-align:center;
```

Comment: This is not quite the same thing. This would be for aligning elements in the same container, versus aligning an element within its own box model. The comment by A Haworth is identifying what my issue is.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).